# AutocompleteInput does not complete word when option is clicked

Tags: bokeh

I'm working in Jupyter notebook 5.7.4 bokeh 1.0.4, Firefox 63.0.3 python3.7, I want to get autocompletion using bokeh to get some interactive visualization.

```
    from bokeh.models.widgets import AutocompleteInput
    from IPython.display import HTML
    input_widget = AutocompleteInput(completions=cList1, title='FTTH Keys', value='value')
    l = layout([[input_widget],], sizing_mode='fixed')

    curdoc().add_root(l)
    curdoc().title = 'UI Test'
    show(l)
```

when I write characters all is fine, but when I want to choose one element from the autocomplete list the word didn't complete in the input box.